# how to add online excel sheet (using google api) in my spring mvc web project for access mysql data

Tags: spring-mvc, google-api, google-sheets-api

I created spring mvc web project. All data stored in mysql databases. I want to display some data using excel sheet. But above excel sheet should be access web browser. Therefor I decided using google sheet api. How I created it....

Comment: welcome to stack.  please show us what you have tried and we will be happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is that make your spreadsheet published to web under the file. This will give you a link something like this 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/(document key)/pubhtml 
and click published.

After that use this link in your http request

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/(document key)/od6/public/values?alt=json

and you will be able to get a json object from your google spreadsheet